# Exception error in arrays

Tags: java, arrays

My code is intended to take in an array of ints and return *an array of ints with a length of twice the original array's length*, minus 2.

The returned array should have values **1/3 and 2/3** between any given two values in the original array.

For example input array:

> {400, 500, 600}

will return:

> {400,433,466,500,533,566,600}

The code I have is as follows:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
            System.out.println("Problem 9 tests");
            int[] arr7={300, 400, 500};
            System.out.println(highDef(arr7));
            System.out.println(" ");

public static int[] highDef(int[] original) {
        int[] newarr = new int[original.length*3-2];
        newarr[0]=original[0];
        int count=0;
        while (count!=newarr.length) {
                int increment=(original[count+1]-original[count])/3;
                newarr[count+1]=original[count]+increment;
                newarr[count+2]=original[count]+(count*increment);
                count+=1;
        }
        return newarr;
```

Comment: What does the exception say?

Comment: while (count!=newarr.length -2 )
add "-2" to the while condition, you can't get newarr[count+1] when count == newarr.length

Comment: Look within your loop - imagine when `count == newarr.length - 2`... but then you're accessing `newarr[count+2]` in the body of the loop. (I'd strongly advise you to use `for` loops for this sort of thing, by the way...)

Comment: error message? please copy paste

Comment: Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 3
 at Lab2a.highDef(Lab2a.java:186)
 at Lab2a.main(Lab2a.java:26)

Comment: it looks to have a problem with this line: int increment=(original[count+1]-original[count])/3;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Haven't looked good enough the first time :)
Here you go:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    System.out.println("Problem 9 tests");
    int[] arr7 = {300, 400, 500};
    System.out.println(Arrays.toString(highDef(arr7)));
    System.out.println(" ");
}

public static int[] highDef(int[] original) {
    int[] newarr = new int[original.length * 3 - 2];
    newarr[original.length * 3 - 3] = original[original.length-1];

    for(int i=0; i<original.length-1; i++){
        newarr[i*3] = original[i];
        int increment = (original[i+1] - original[i])/3;
        newarr[i*3+1] = original[i] + increment;
        newarr[i*3+2] = original[i] + increment*2;
    }

    return newarr;
}
```

Comment: Still receiving the same out of bounds exception :(

Comment: This was very helpful in helping me understand what the exception means, but for some reason adding -3 to the while condition still did not fix the error. I'm not sure why

Answer (score 0):

With **array out of bound exceptions**, try to think of the last case.

In your example:

**original.length = 3**

**newarr.length = (original.length * 3) - 2 = 7**

```
while (count!=newarr.length) // this means: while count does not equal to 7. Therefore *Count* value can go upto 6
// imagine the last case, count = 6
newarr[count+2]=original[count]+(count*increment); // the problem is here
// count(6) + 2 = 8, which is out of bounds
```

same issue with this line: `int increment=(original[count+1]-original[count])/3;`

**count** will go upto 6 but `original[count+1]` = `original[7]` which is out of bound as well